# can i pass longitude and latitude in Google map JS API call ?

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps

Im using Google map JS API and i want to pass longitude and latitude dynamically in the call is it possible ?

```
<script async defer 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=%CLIEN_ID%&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Is there any way to pass a longitude and a latitude in this call and use them in the init map function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this properly. The idea is :

1- put 2 hidden inputs in the view with the value of the first one will contain the lng the second will contain the lat. I'm using smarty template engine:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lng" id="lng" value="{$lng}">
<input type="hidden" name="lat" id="lat" value="{$lat}">
```

2- call the maps js api like simply with just the callback=initMap

```
<script async defer 
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=%CLIEN_ID%&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

3- put your initMap function in a js file and you will get the lng and lat values from the hidden inputs using jquery.

```
function initMap() {
    var longitude = $("#lng").val();
    var latitude  = $("#lat").val();              
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: latitude, lng: longitude},
        zoom: 8
    });
}
```

And it worked.

Answer (score -1):

How do you mean? You set the lat and lng when you setup and initialize the map, the following code is from google developers code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Google Map</h1>

<div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>

<script>
function myMap() {
var mapProp= {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:5,
};
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=myMap"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because im using this in a page that the longitude and the latitude are dynamic. The logitude and the latitude are returned from a controller and when the view is rendered i need to call the api with the returned langitude and latitude

Comment: ok, so for example if you do a mysql query in PHP, you could simply just echo out the result. center:new google.maps.LatLng(<? echo $lat ?>,<? echo $lng ?>) or put them in variables first. Same with Javascript. Put up some code to look at

Comment: I told you the longitude latitude are passed from a controller wich means im using an MVC framework (custom company framework) the view is smarty template engine so that will not help ...

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set up lat and long calls in the URL, pass them as parameters as such:

`...api/js?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&client=%CLIEN_ID%&callback=initMap`

Make sure there are no spaces anywhere in your latlng.

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: And how to get them in the initMap function , this is my code : 

function initMap() {

                                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                                  center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                                  zoom: 8
                                });
                            }

Comment: Your best bet is to use JS to parse the URL for the latlng parameter and then use that data inside your initMap function. Otherwise there's no way that you can pass data unless initMap parameter supports something such as `initMap(<data here>)`.

That being said, I'm confused by what you're trying to achieve. You seem to already have your lat and longs defined in your initMap function.